# Android SmsMessage return incorrect decode

Tags: android, android-emulator

I used Receiver to capture incoming SMS. But come across this problem:

When sending Chinese SMS(你好,for example), the receiver is called correctly.

After extracting the *pdus*, building the SmsMessage,the SmsMessage.getMessageBody() returns incorrect decoding of USC2, which I assume.

In the above example:
你好 is the only userData, which is encoded to **0x4F60 0x590d** in the pdus.
I saw this in debugger.
However,the **getMessageBody()** return a String, who content is **\u004f \u00a1 \u0065 \u006a**.

I read the source code, but still cannot understand why.
Any help?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the encoding ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html

Comment: I didn't send the message in the programm. The SMS is sent by another emulator, so I assume it's done by the Message app builtin android.